# Как переписать регулярное выражение под русские команды?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
/(\/\w+)((\s)([a-z0-9\._\-+%]+))?(\s[a-z0-9\._\-+%]+)?/gi
```

> /ping fb.com

Как из данного regex сделать, чтобы была поддержка русского языка

> /пинг fb.com

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `\w+` на `(?:\w+|[a-яё]+)`

Comment: действительно, спасибо